# Xamarin.Android how i can get position and margin to elements which are generated from the code?

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin.android

Problems with position elements which generating from code
i will try to place it in center and give them margin (left right) from previous elements.
tried use LinearLayout, RowLayout, but all result are the same (staying center in each other).
Like a [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhKhI.png)

```
        public void testImageAdd(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {

            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
            relativeLayoutParams.SetMargins(30,20,30,0);
            relativeLayoutParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);




            #region team1 Elements
            ImageView firstTeamLogo = new ImageView(this);
            firstTeamLogo.LayoutParameters = relativeLayoutParams;

            TextView firstTeamText = new TextView(this);
            firstTeamText.Text = "testTeam1";
            firstTeamText.LayoutParameters = relativeLayoutParams;

            var firstTeamLogoBitmap = ImageDownloader.GetImageBitmapFromUrl("");
            firstTeamLogo.SetImageBitmap(firstTeamLogoBitmap);
            #endregion

            #region team2 Elements
            ImageView secondTeamLogo = new ImageView(this);
            secondTeamLogo.LayoutParameters = relativeLayoutParams;

            TextView secondTeamText = new TextView(this);
            secondTeamText.Text = "testTeam2";
            secondTeamText.LayoutParameters = relativeLayoutParams;

            var secondTeamLogoTeamLogoBitmap = ImageDownloader.GetImageBitmapFromUrl("");
            secondTeamLogo.SetImageBitmap(secondTeamLogoTeamLogoBitmap);
            #endregion

            TextView versusText = new TextView(this);
            versusText.Text = "vs";
            versusText.LayoutParameters = relativeLayoutParams;




            relativeLayout.AddView(firstTeamLogo);
            relativeLayout.AddView(firstTeamText);
            relativeLayout.AddView(versusText);
            relativeLayout.AddView(secondTeamText);
            relativeLayout.AddView(secondTeamLogo);
            SetContentView(relativeLayout, relativeLayoutParams2);
```

What did i do wrong? And i think i'm calling the drawing of elements incorrectly (is there a bit of code duplication?).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `RelativeLayout`  with `LinearLayout` , your code works fine on my side .

#### Update

You can add `relativeLayout.SetGravity(GravityFlags.CenterVertical);` to make the elements center in vertical , but another problem would happen ,all the elements would be placed to the center of the screen(vertically).

To solve the problem we should add another  `LinearLayout` as root layout.

Refer to the following code

```cs
LinearLayout relativeLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
 
relativeLayout.SetGravity(GravityFlags.CenterVertical);
relativeLayout.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);



LinearLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
relativeLayoutParams.SetMargins(10, 20, 30, 10);
            

#region team1 Elements
ImageView firstTeamLogo = new ImageView(this);
firstTeamLogo.LayoutParameters = relativeLayoutParams;

TextView firstTeamText = new TextView(this);
firstTeamText.Text = "testTeam1";
firstTeamText.LayoutParameters = relativeLayoutParams;

//var firstTeamLogoBitmap = ImageDownloader.GetImageBitmapFromUrl("");
//firstTeamLogo.SetImageBitmap(firstTeamLogoBitmap);
firstTeamLogo.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.myIcon);


#endregion

#region team2 Elements
ImageView secondTeamLogo = new ImageView(this);
secondTeamLogo.LayoutParameters = relativeLayoutParams;

TextView secondTeamText = new TextView(this);
secondTeamText.Text = "testTeam2";
secondTeamText.LayoutParameters = relativeLayoutParams;

//var secondTeamLogoTeamLogoBitmap = ImageDownloader.GetImageBitmapFromUrl("");
//secondTeamLogo.SetImageBitmap(secondTeamLogoTeamLogoBitmap);

secondTeamLogo.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.a);
#endregion

TextView versusText = new TextView(this);
versusText.Text = "vs";
versusText.LayoutParameters = relativeLayoutParams;


relativeLayout.AddView(firstTeamLogo);
relativeLayout.AddView(firstTeamText);
relativeLayout.AddView(versusText);
relativeLayout.AddView(secondTeamText);
relativeLayout.AddView(secondTeamLogo);

LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(this);
parent.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Top);
parent.AddView(relativeLayout);

SetContentView(parent, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent));
```

[image]

Comment: <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJjFj.png" alt="img"> 
Unfortunately, it does not work

Comment: Now they're staying center left 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/grd8a.png

Comment: Did you use my code ? This is implemented with 2 layouts(LinearLayout).

Comment: Hi , did you solve the problem?